# Why can't I assign a function directly?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This code calls the `f()` function:

```
<p id="firstp">Hello!</p> 
<script>
  function f() {
    doSomething();
  };
  document.getElementById("firstp").onmouseover = function() {
      f();
  };
</script>
```

Yet if I write it this way, it stops working:

```
  document.getElementById("firstp").onmouseover = f();
```

Why doesn't the event handler get set when I call the function directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you don't want to call the function, you want just to tell the browser that it should call it when mouseover event happens. `f()` (round brackets after function's name) calls the function and assigns to `.onmouseover` what `f` returns. You want to assign the reference to `f` to `.onmouseover`, so what you are looking for is

```
document.getElementById("firstp").onmouseover = f;
```